# How to add user without useradd command?

Tags: password, users, passwd-file

Is it possible to add a user in ubuntu linux without useradd command I think its possible by adding the entries in `/etc/passwd and /etc/shadow` but i don't know the exact steps to do it and the user should get its home directory and bash shell too.

Answer (score 19):

It's not recommended to manually modify `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group` or `/etc/gshadow` because the risk of breakage. If you're looking for an alternative command that is easier to use, take a look at [`adduser(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man5/adduser.8.html). All you have to run is:

```
sudo adduser user
```

The shell will be `/bin/bash` by default per `/etc/adduser.conf`.

Usually, if you wish to add a user with the bash shell, thereby create a home directory `/home/user` and a user group, you would use:

```
sudo useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash --user-group user
```

This command is basically determining a free User ID `$UID` and Group ID `$GID` and then executing the next commands:

```
echo "user:x:$UID:$GID::/home/user:/bin/bash" | sudo tee -a /etc/passwd
echo "user:x:$GID:" | sudo tee -a /etc/group
echo "user:!:$DATE_OF_LAST_PASS_CHANGE:0:99999:7:::" | sudo tee -a /etc/shadow
echo "user:!::" | sudo tee -a /etc/gshadow
```

..and thereby possibly making a backup of the files.

The next manual pages about the file formats may be of interest to you:

- [`passwd(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man5/passwd.5.html)
- [`group(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man5/group.5.html)
- [`shadow(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man5/shadow.5.html)
- [`gshadow(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man5/gshadow.5.html)

Comment: hey, Lekensteyn, did you miss this first part of their post? "Is it possible to add a user in ubuntu linux without useradd command..."  They want a solution without useradd :/

Comment: @TheEvilPhoenix: I thought he was asking about an alternative for `adduser`. I've now included `adduser` as answer. It's indeed "without useradd" :)

Comment: No problem, wanted to point it out is all.  and forgive me being semiconfrontational... long, bad days at work with cascade server failure does that to ya...

Comment: @All I want to create user without useradd by adding possible entries in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

Comment: this is not what i wanted.

Comment: @mr_eclair: I've included how to add a user to `/etc/passwd`. The group changes are optional but recommended. What else do you expect?

Comment: Very helpful answer! What's the reason to use `tee -a` instead of `>>`?

Comment: @m59 `>>` tries to open a file as the current (non-root) user which will fail with a Permission denied error. Using `sudo tee` bypasses that. Alternatively, you could wrap the command in a `sudo sh -c '...'` to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although not usually necessary or recommended, the answer to the question of *How to add user without useradd command* is to use `sudo vipw`

This will launch your system-defined editor while locking the passwd file. Enter a line for a new user. (In vi, shift-G to get to the last line then yy p to duplicate it.) Edit the username and create a unique user ID number.

After saving the file and exiting the editor, you'll be prompted to edit /etc/shadow. Use the same technique to create a new line and use "*" for the password hash. The new account is locked. Use `passwd username` to unlock it and set a password.

It's also necessary to create a home directory, copy files from the skeleton directory, set group permissions, etc. But `vipw` is your main resource. See also `vigr`.

Source: http://itguykelly.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/manually-add-new-user-to-red-hatfedoracentos/ (yes, these commands work across various flavors of *nix)

Answer (score 0):

When the user is created in the system it has effect on the files such as /etc/passed , /etc/group , /etc/shadow  so go through these files and make the manual entry .
       And finally from /etc/skel file add skeleton for user in user's home directory which you have to create in home directory.