# useradd seems to have failed in Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: login, lubuntu, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add user without useradd command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54992/how-to-add-user-without-useradd-command)

I am trying to add users in Lubuntu 12.04. I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-new-linux-user-account/) which amounts to:

```
$ useradd username
$ passwd username
```

I entered the password twice, and everything seemed good. But when I try to use the username and password from the Lubuntu login screen, it fails, simply returning to the login screen.

(Note that this is not the 'incorrect password' behavior that my working account displays.)

Any ideas?

Comment: It may be a bug...I face it in UBUNTU 12.04 too.Try loging in in the terminal.If it successfully logs in in the terminal then its a bug in the log in display manager part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than the low level utility `useradd` on a Debian based distribution (like Lubuntu)  it is recommended to use [adduser](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto). This makes sure all defaults are installed correctly, and a user HOME is created appropriately.

Usage:

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

Comment: This is really somewhat humorous. Thanks much `adduser` does what I want, I wonder if I'll be able to remember which is which.

Comment: @EricWilson If you ever become confused you can run `man adduser` and `man useradd` to see documentation and usage information for both commands.

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu has a graphical administration tool for this. Go to:

> LXDE Menu > System Tools > Users and Groups

(Or, if you prefer, run the command `users-admin`.)