# Unable to create and delete an user account in the PC

Tags: user-management, useradd

When I try to create a new user account with command `sudo adduser test-ser`, I receive this error:
    sudo adduser test-user

```
Adding user test-user ...
Adding new group test-user (1069) ...
Adding new user 'test-user' (1032) with group 'test-user' ...
useradd: existing lock file /etc/subgid.lock without a PID
useradd: cannot lock /etc/subgid; try again later.
adduser: '/usr/sbin/useradd -d /home/test-user -g test-user -s /bin/bash -u 1032 test-user' returned error code 18. Exiting.
```

When I try to delete an already existing account I receive this error:

```
sudo deluser --remove-home existinguser
```

```
Looking for files to backup/remove ...
Removing user `existinguser' ...
Warning: group `existinguser' has no more members.
userdel: existing lock file /etc/subgid.lock without a PID
userdel: cannot lock /etc/subgid; try again later.
/usr/sbin/deluser: `/usr/sbin/userdel existinguser' returned error code 18. Exiting.
```

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo fuser /etc/subgid` ?

Comment: `testuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Comment: No, run it as user `base`

Comment: Erm... You posted 2x the same command output in your question. You probably copied the wrong command? And what about a reboot? That helps sometimes with lockfiles and does not hurt.

Comment: `sudo fuser /etc/subgid` if i do this command as user `base` nothing happens:

`base@base-vb:~$ sudo fuser /etc/subgid
base@base-vb:~$ `

i already rebooted but nothing :)

Comment: [We should not create a new account with `useradd`. Use `adduser` instead](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139304/useradd-seems-to-have-failed-in-lubuntu-12-04)

Comment: I edited my question to reply to you @Takkat

Comment: I formatted my question correctly thanks to @heemayl :-)

Comment: @gtaflow when you add in lots of lines of code, please add 4 spaces before each line, rather than individual `code` blocks for each line. Also, rather than `<br>` just add 2 spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: Help me guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> useradd: existing lock file /etc/subgid.lock without a PID
> ```

SInce it's this lock file that's causing the problem, and since it is without a PID (meaning there's no running process that's holding the lock and this is just some leftover of a previous attempt), I think you can delete it safely. Then try again.

Comment: Is there a command to force deletion of the file? I'm installing nautilus to do it.

Comment: @gtaflow it's likely owned by root. `sudo rm /etc/subgid.lock` should do it.

Comment: muru, what puzzled me is that `reboot` does not solve the issue, should not reboot make things even if a process has leftovers as far as lock files are concerned?

Comment: @heemayl not unless the lock file is on a transient file system like `tmpfs`.

Comment: Ah..makes sense..