# Create user and SSH key via script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh

I'm working a script that create user and add a key for that user
so he can use that key with his username to SSH into my VM

Ex. user = john

```
useradd -m john &&
cd ~/.ssh/ && 
rm -rf tmp_rsa* &&
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "john@email.com" -N '' -f john_rsa &&
echo "#tmp_rsa" >> authorized_keys &&
cat john_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys &&
cat authorized_keys &&
service ssh restart &&
echo ">>> Done"
```

Is the above script is correct to acheive what I want ?

I tried connect with UN : `john`, and the key generated `john_rsa`.

I got

[image]

---

Thanks to **@marosg** and **@Takkat**

**Here is my updated script**

```
adduser -m john &&
cd ~/.ssh/ && 
rm -rf tmp_rsa* &&
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "john@email.com" -N '' -f john_rsa &&
echo "#tmp_rsa" >> ~john/.ssh/authorized_keys &&
cat john_rsa.pub >> ~john/.ssh/authorized_keys &&
cat authorized_keys &&
echo ">>> Done"
```

Comment: The command `useradd` will not create a home directory for john, but `adduser` will. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/139304/useradd-seems-to-have-failed-in-lubuntu-12-04

Comment: @Takkat what about the `-m` ?

Comment: @Takkat : What you think of my updated script ?

Comment: There is no option `-m` in Ubuntu. The home directory will be created by default in `/home/` - after that it appears you may want to create your keys as user `john`.

Comment: So this should do right ? `adduser -m john`

Comment: as said, `adduser` does not take an option `-m` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong here:

- you create user john and then you do nothing with this user any more
- You are adding keys to YOUR user
- remote user who needs to login here needs the private key from ssh keypair on the machine from which he is connecting
- there is no need to restart ssh service after adding keys

What you need on client side

- user generates ssh keypair and provides you public key of this keypair
  (`ssh-keygen ...; cat id_rsa.pub`)

What you need on server side is

- add user john
- add the public key provided by user to ~john/.ssh/authorized_keys
  (`echo id_rsa.pub_provided_by_remote_user >> ~john/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

Comment: I want to do the whole things in 1 script, can you help me adjust what I got. I can update what I got now base on your suggestion, and update my post. Is it ok ?

Comment: What you think of my updated script ?

Comment: If you and that other user are two different humans, it is not possible to do this in one script securely.

1 . User John creates keypair on his machine, there is private key, which is secret and he keeps it on his machine. There is public key, which he sends you as a text

2. On server you create user john and then put that public key to his ~john/.ssh/authorized_keys

Above you use `cd ~/.ssh/` which means you are working in YOUR .ssh directory, you need to use ~john/.ssh

Comment: If user John has Launchpad account then you can use ssh-import and he does not need to send you his public key but I think this would be too complicated to your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
set -euo pipefail

DEV_GROUP="somegroup"
sudo groupadd --force "${DEV_GROUP}"

function adduser() {
    local var_user="$1"
    shift 
    local var_ssh_pub_key="$*"
    id --user "${var_user}" &>/dev/null || sudo useradd --gid "${DEV_GROUP}" --groups wheel,docker "${var_user}"
    echo "${var_user} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee "/etc/sudoers.d/${var_user}"
    sudo --user "${var_user}" mkdir -p "/home/${var_user}/.ssh"
    sudo --user "${var_user}" touch "/home/${var_user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    echo "${var_ssh_pub_key}" | sudo --user "${var_user}" tee "/home/${var_user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
}

adduser someuser ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1.... user@host
```