# Name of newly created user missing features in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, shutdown, users

Hi I am not very experienced with user management in ubuntu.
I needed to create a new user to manage my application server so following some instructions online, this is what i did:

I became root

```
sudo -i
```

I added a group

```
addgroup jbossgroup
```

I added a user and assigned it to a group

```
useradd -g jbossgroup jboss
```

I created a password

```
passwd jboss
```

Then I changed the ownership of a folder to check that the user was correctly created and that working fine.

```
chown jboss:jbossgroup /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/ -R
```

I made this user sudoer

```
gpasswd -a jboss sudo
```

But i think this is not working since when I use mkdir or rm... in a folder owned by root, i have to type sudo.(**Did i do this step correctly?**)

The next thing I noticed was that when i changed to the newly created user, the terminal
only displayed this:

```
$
```

So I fixed that by doing this as the jboss user:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

I have some doubts

- Did I correctly create this user and is it safe to work with it?
- Why the name of the user doesn't appear in the drop down menu when I click the shutdown button(Next to the time in the top right corner of the screen)?
- Also I noticed that in the home folder there is not a jboss folder. Why this was not created?
- What other features this user might be missing?

Comment: Rather than with `useradd` you should create a new user with `adduser`. See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/139304/useradd-seems-to-have-failed-in-lubuntu-12-04, http://askubuntu.com/questions/54992/how-to-add-user-without-useradd-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have achieved your goal in only three steps:

`sudo adduser jboss`

`sudo passwd jboss`    you have to supply the password :)

`sudo adduser jboss sudo`    adds *jboss* to the group *sudo*

And please be aware that `gpasswd` is the wrong tool to add a user to a group!